# Public Static Class in same namespace as web form can't be resolved

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, namespaces, scope

I have a Webform MVP project and have some extensions methods declared in a class at App_Code folder that are not resolved in my webform code behind. both Webform and Static Class are in same namespace but something seems to not be working...

I did a quick sample to show you the issue...

Class at App_Code:

```
namespace ecommerce.mvp
{
    public static class Class1
    {
        public static void Test1()
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


namespace ecommerce.mvp
{
    public partial class pdp : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Class1.Test1(); // <--- This symbol can't be resolved
```

Notice that both are at same namespace...but for some reason Class1 is not resolved at code behind...

I really will appreciate any help on that one.
Thanks.

Comment: Are they in the same assembly? If not, is the assembly holding `Class1` referenced by the other?

Comment: (A visual studio project is usually an assembly, in case you're wondering)

Comment: test it by moving the definition of Class 1 to the same file with the pdp, and if it works report!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on your Class1.cs class in the App_Code folder and check its properties. **Build Action** must be set to **Compile**. (Sometimes it is set to **Content**)

Comment: Great! It worked perfectly! Many Many Thanks! should not set VS .cs .vb files to "Compile" Automatically when you copy it from another project or add it from scratch???

Comment: By default App_Code classes are not available or accessible you need to set Build Action manually everytime you add a new class to App_Code folder

Comment: Ok, but does not have any sense or it?

Comment: Donno exactly, App_Code seems not to be recommanded within a project created with the Web Application Project (it is often used within Website Project). One Advantage of App_Code is that you can find it in the Bin folder at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

Just because 2 classes share the same namespace does not mean they are automatically visible to each other *if they are in different assemblies/projects*.

The only way I can see you having this problem is if `Class1` is in assembly/project "Foo" (a made up name), and class `pdp` is in assembly/project "Bar" (another made up name).

To resolve this you'd need to add a reference to the assembly holding `Class1` to the assembly holding `pdp`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem, however, it was a different 'Project' that was complaining. In my case, I found out that there were some .cs files which were included as 'link', and I did not include my new .cs file as 'link' in the project that was complaining. Hope this might help someone who stumbles upon this. So, a word of advice: When error is listed in 'Error list', also check the 'Project' column as well.